# How to force page break in "longtblr" environment?

Tags: page-breaking, longtblr

I have a very long table in a `longtblr` environment.

I want to enforce a page-break at a certain position. How do I do that?
The MWE is attached herewith.
Note, I have tried `\pagebreak`, `\newpage`, `\\*`, but none of these works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {ABC},
    label = {tab:test},
]{
    width = \textwidth,
    colspec= {X[0.75,c] X[0.5,c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]},
    rowhead = 2,
}
\small
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ID}} & \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Concept ID}} \\ \cline{3-7} 
& & {\textbf{1}} & {\textbf{2}} & {\textbf{3}} & {\textbf{4}} & {\textbf{5}} \\ \hline
% similar block of multirow
\multirow{5}{*}{IIIA} & $A$ & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} \\ \cline{2-7} 
& $G$ & {H} & {I} & {J} & {K} & {L} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $M$ & {N} & {O} & {P} & {Q} & {R} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $S$ & {T} & {U} & {V} & {W} & {X} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $Y$ & {Z} & {AA} & {AB} & {AC} & {AD} \\ \hline
%% I WANT TO ENFORCE PAGE BREAK HERE
\multirow{5}{*}{IIIB} & $AE$ & {AF} & {AG} & {AH} & {AI} & {AJ} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $AK$ & {AL} & {AM} & {AN} & {AO} & {AP} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $AQ$ & {AR} & {AS} & {AT} & {AU} & {AV} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $AW$ & {AX} & {AY} & {AZ} & {BA} & {BB} \\* \cline{2-7} 
& $BC$ & {BD} & {BE} & {BF} & {BG} & {BH} \\* \hline
% similar block of multirow
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pagebreak` works for me.

Don't use `\multirow` with `tabularray`, use `\SetCell` instead.

You can also take advantage of the package feature to set the first two lines bold `row{1-2} = {font=\bfseries}`, or the second column as math mode column{2}={mode=math} (so you don't need to use `$...$` in every cell of that column).

You may also use `hline{2-Z}={solid}` to avoid the `\cline`s and `\hline`s (thanks to Zarko for the suggestion).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {ABC},
    label = {tab:test},
]{
    width = \textwidth,
    colspec= {X[0.75,c] X[0.5,c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]},
    rowhead = 2,
    hline{2-Z}={solid},
    column{2}={mode=math},
    columns={font=\small},
    row{1-2} = {font=\bfseries}
}
\SetCell[r=2]{h} ID & \SetCell[r=2]{h} & Concept ID \\ 
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
% similar block of multirow
\SetCell[r=5]{h} IIIA & A & {B} & {C} & {D} & {E} & {F} \\  
& G & {H} & {I} & {J} & {K} & {L} \\ 
& M & {N} & {O} & {P} & {Q} & {R} \\  
& S & {T} & {U} & {V} & {W} & {X} \\  
& Y & {Z} & {AA} & {AB} & {AC} & {AD} \\ 
%% I WANT TO ENFORCE PAGE BREAK HERE
\pagebreak 
\SetCell[r=5]{h} IIIB & AE & {AF} & {AG} & {AH} & {AI} & {AJ}\\ 
& AK & {AL} & {AM} & {AN} & {AO} & {AP} \\ 
& AQ & {AR} & {AS} & {AT} & {AU} & {AV} \\  
& AW & {AX} & {AY} & {AZ} & {BA} & {BB} \\  
& BC & {BD} & {BE} & {BF} & {BG} & {BH} \\ 
% similar block of multirow
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `hlines` to table preamble and than remove all `\hline` and `\cline` in table body. Result will be the same, but code is a bit shorter.

Comment: @Zarko `hlines` add a line also at the beginning of the table, I added `hline{2-Z}={solid}`. Thanks!

Comment: ah, table without  `\hline` on the top. To my taste a bit strange ... ;-). The first +1 was mine, for nice answer!

Comment: @Zarko I replicated what the OP did, not my taste as well :)

Comment: I have tried to paste your code into my file to see what happens. Unfortunately, this is not working for me. And I am unable to add a photo in the comment as well. But let me describe what the error is-
1. The page break does not work; the table is still on one page.
2.  Column is full black. Probably, this is the error [Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `mode'.]
3. "hline{2-Z}={solid}," this line is also not working and showing the error- [Missing number, treated as zero.]

Comment: @RounakNiloy Do you have an up-to-date distrubution?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Sorry, I am not aware of this. In fact, I am writing on a thesis template provided by my university. I have searched for up-to-date in the preamble but could not find any such. Should I search for something very specific?

Comment: @RounakNiloy Did you install LaTeX on your computer? TeX Live or MiKTeX?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am working in Overleaf.

Comment: @RounakNiloy I created my MWE in Overleaf, too, and it works. Choose 2023 as TeX Live version from the side menu.

Comment: @RounakNiloy This is my Overleaf project without errors: https://www.overleaf.com/read/htxxbsgkjkmh

Comment: @CarLaTeX, "Choose 2023 as TeX Live version" this solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @RounakNiloy You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!